# Increase the count of instances in an autoscaling group using AWS CLI or Python

Tags: python, boto3, aws-cli, autoscaling, amazon-ami

I've been trying to fetch list of autoscaling groups with a specific tag. The below script does this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3
import base64
import time

client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name='us-west-2')
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100}
)

filtered_asgs = page_iterator.search(
    'AutoScalingGroups[] | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format(
        'Application', 'CCP')
)

for asg in filtered_asgs:
#    print asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
```

Now, I am trying to double the number of instances in each ASG from the output list. I have a new Launch configuration with a new AMI and that I have already pushed in to this ASG. Now doubling the instance count will be creating new instances within this ASG using new with new AMI. Please suggest on how to double the instance count..

Answer (score -1):

For doing this first you have to create a new launch configuration for updated image-id because you cannot modify launch configurations:

```
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration \ 
--launch-configuration-name my-launch-config \ 
--image-id ami-c6169af6 --instance-type m1.medium
```

Then attached created launch configuration to auto-scaling

```
update-auto-scaling-group \
--auto-scaling-group-name <value> \ 
--launch-configuration-name <value> \
--min-size <value> --max-size <value>
```

After doing this it will double the no. of instances and all new instances will be with new image.

But all old instances are still with old image-id so you have to delete those instances once launch-configuration is updated.

As soon as you delete the instance auto-scaling will spin up new instances with new image id.

This methodology of doing updates is called rolling updates.

---

Other Method is blue-green approach in which

1. create one new launch configuration
2. create new auto-scaling group

As soon as your new stack is ready attach it to your ELB or what ever approach you are using and delete old one.

Both approaches will have their own use cases depends upon your use requirements:

If you want your all instances to be sync all the time go for second approach

Comment: I've already scripted to created new LC with new AMI ID. That is fine. I am stuck at doubling the instance count in new ASG. 

`update-auto-scaling-group \
--auto-scaling-group-name <value> \ 
--launch-configuration-name <value> \
--min-size <value> --max-size <value>`

Using this one I can set a particular number of instance I know. But how do I get number of  instances in these ASGs and double it within script ?!.

Comment: You can use describe-autoscaling to get the autoscaling params get MinSize and MaxSize